# HttpWebResponse not returning 404

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking to check for a series of images on a site, which may or may not exist using a `HttpWebRequest`. However, even when a non-existant image URL is used, the response still contains a 200 OK status code.

The sites being checked are all using Custom 404 pages, but are returning the correct 404 code when checked with Firebug/Fiddler.

```cs
public HttpStatusCode GetHeaders(string url)
{
    HttpStatusCode result = default(HttpStatusCode);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    //request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    //request.Method = "GET";
    try
    {
        using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                result = response.StatusCode;
                response.Close();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {                    
        return HttpStatusCode.NotFound;                    
    }
}
```

Any Ideas? I've been trying to sort this on-and-off for two weeks now.

Comment: Do you have any sample URLs? Are you sure the pages aren't returning a 200 that uses HTML to redirect to the 404 page?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to provide sample URLS as the sites are still in development. The page is definitely returning a 404 though.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the Server redirects you to a available "not found" page?
Try deactivating AutoRedirect.

```
  webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false; 
  ...
  webRequest.Timeout = 1000;
```

Then check for a redirection.
When this does not work, I guess you have to parse the website and look out for a string like "not found"...

Comment: Have tried this and still no luck. I'm able to get it to work by checking for the content-type of the response (image/jpeg will be successful) however this seems to be much slower to execute.

Comment: instead of an random image it returns an 404 image? what about checking the filename?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear; a successful result will have a content type of `image/jpeg` and unsuccessful will be the 404 page which is html. So I can check this, but as mentioned it is slow!

Comment: It will be slow because the server needs time to redirect. you should set a shorter timeout to avoid this. actually it's possible you're loosing images this way in case the server is busy. You could raise the time for timeout in case there are lots of timeouts.